# Generate Bootstrap button with icon with JSF

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jsf, button, icons

I'm trying to creating a button based on bootstrap original template, this is the original HTML Button :

```
<button class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
    <i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i>
</button>
```

I tried in this way:

```
<h:button
    outcome="#{cc.attrs.managedBeanName.redirectCriarBean(cc.attrs.targetPage)}"
    rendered="#{cc.attrs.showButtonCadastrar}"
    styleClass="btn btn-default btn-sm">
    <i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i>
</h:button>
```

But this is the html generated:

```
<input type="button" onclick="window.location.href='/cardoso/core/banca/manter_banca.xhtml?action=novo'; return false;" value="" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
<i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i>
```

I tried with this:

```
<h:commandButton action="#{cc.attrs.managedBeanName.redirectCriarBean(cc.attrs.targetPage)}"
    rendered="#{cc.attrs.showButtonCadastrar}"
    styleClass="btn btn-default btn-sm">
    <i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i>
</h:commandButton>
```

But the result is wrost:

```
<input type="submit" name="j_idt40:j_idt72" value="" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
<i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i>
```

Always the icon out of button:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<h:button>` and `<h:commandButton>` indeed doesn't allow children.

Use `<h:link>` instead, it allows children and Bootstrap also [supports](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons) `btn` styles on `<a>` elements.

```
<h:link ... styleClass="btn btn-default btn-sm">
    <i class="fa fa-plus-square" />
</h:link>
```

Additional advantage, it's better for SEO as `<button>` and `<h:button>` needs JavaScript `window.location` for the navigation, while the `<h:link>` renders a true `<a href>`. Searchbots usually don't follow JavaScript. The `<h:commandButton>` is a bad choice for page-to-page navigation as it fires a POST request instead of a GET request.

If you really want to have a `<button>` element in the markup, then you can always use plain HTML. It's also supported in JSF. For conditional rendering, wrap it in an `<ui:fragment>`.

```
<ui:fragment rendered="...">
    <button ... onclick="window.location.href='#{cc.attrs.managedBeanName.redirectCriarBean(cc.attrs.targetPage)}';return false">
        <i class="fa fa-plus-square" />
    </button>
</ui:fragment>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, worked. Not exactly the same HTML generated (because generate a <a> as you said) but the button generated in view is exactly the same.

Comment: You're welcome. I updated the answer in case you really want to have a `<button>` in the markup.